# reading tiff images in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm trying to read a TIFF (Sometimes PNG) image using matplotlib and building a class to be able to read and plot multiple images associated with an object. The code inside the class definition is not important right now.

But I have one question. When I include the last para in the code before the class definition I am able to read and show the image, but when I include it after the class definition it doesn't work.
Can someone help me as to why this is happening?

I have tried this with single and multiple images

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import random
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

fig,line,labels,ax={},{},[50],{}
X=[3000]
Y=[3000]
Z=[3000]
titles=r'microscopy'

class plotter:

    def figures(self, heading, titles, ax, fig, style, lxlim, uxlim, lylim, uylim, xlabel, ylabel):
    self.heading=heading
    self.titles=titles
    self.ax=ax
    self.fig=fig
    self.style=style
    plt.style.use(self.style)
    self.fig=plt.figure(self.heading)
    self.ax=self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.lxlim=lxlim
    self.uxlim=uxlim
    self.lylim=lylim
    self.uylim=uylim
    self.ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    self.ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    self.ax.grid(True)
    #self.ax.grid(False)
    self.ax.set_xlim([lxlim, uxlim])
    self.ax.set_ylim([lylim, uylim])
    self.ax.set_title(self.titles,style='italic')
    #self.ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))
    self.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(50))
    self.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(12))
    self.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))
    self.ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(10))
    #self.ax.invert_yaxis()
    #self.ax.xaxis.tick_top()
    #self.ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
    #self.ax.tick_params(labelbottom='off',labeltop='on')
    #column_labels = list('ABCD')
    #row_labels = list('WXYZ')
    #self.ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
    #self.ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
    #self.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    #self.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    #self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
    #ticks=np.linspace(200,700,26,endpoint=False)
    #ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', bottom=True)
    #self.ax.set_xticks(ticks,minor=True)
    #self.fig.savefig('figure.png', bbox_inches='tight')

styler = dict(size=11, color='brown')
spectra=plotter()
spectra.figures('Fibres', 'Fibres', ax, fig, 'classic', None, None, None,None,None,None)

image1=mpimg.imread('geter.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(image1)
#spectra.ax.imshow(image1)
plt.show()
#spectra.ax.axis('off')
```

When I include the last paragraph before the class definition it gives the right read image data but when it is after the class definition (as is shown in the code now), I just get an image with axes and plain yellow color. I'm unable to understand why. My image is basically just a screenshot of some folder arrangement.
Right now I have not yet bound the object axes with displaying the image since my class definition is not complete. But I want to know why this is happening.

2) And a second thing is that when I use

```
spectra.ax.imshow(....)
```

in place of

```
plt.imshow(....)
```

The code doesn't work and gives the same yellow tint image.

Comment: why do you have `fig` and `ax` as inputs to the `plotter.figures` function, when you are just going to overwrite them with `plt.figure` and `fig.add_subplot` anyway?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying.
I am trying to pass an array of axes and figures and at a later point display subplots with multiple images in each of the figure windows. So I figured it's best if I keep each axis independent and pass an axis object to it as input.

Comment: Sure that makes sense. But then you don't need to create the figure and axes inside the function, do you?

Comment: True, you're right. I just removed that but it still gives me the same result.